# Bash trap not being executed after python exits with error

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, python-3.x

I have the following bash script that runs on Ubuntu 12:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [[ -f ".build.lock" ]]; then
   echo "A build is already in progress by another user. Unable to continue, exiting."
   echo "   If this is a mistake, delete the '.build.lock' file to forcefully unlock"
   exit 1
else
   touch .build.lock
   echo "Build Lock Created"

   pushd ~/build-server-scripts > /dev/null

   # Execute main build script
   python3 my-build.py "$@"

   popd > /dev/null
fi

__cleanup()
{
   echo "Build Lock Removed"
   [[ -f ".build.lock" ]] && rm ".build.lock"
}

trap __cleanup EXIT
```

Whenever I throw an exception from my python script (most are unhandled), I expect the bash script to subsequently fail as well and execute the TRAP. However, it does not. What am I missing here?

Here is an example of how I handle errors in my python (Using python 3.2) script:

```
try:
   # Do lots of other business logic here

   # 'os.setsid' needed to terminate process later for interrupts.
   process = subprocess.Popen('./ziosk-build.sh', preexec_fn=os.setsid)
   process.communicate()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print('\n\nSIGINT (CTRL+C?) received; stopping\n')
   try:
      os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
   except NameError:
      pass

except RuntimeError as e:
   print('>>> ERROR >>>', e)
   sys.exit(1)
```

In the script above, I handle a few exceptions explicitly. When I get a keyboard interrupt, I want to exit and the bash script it is called from should clean up the build lock with the trap. When any other runtime error occurs, I also handle and print it for context & information.

There are of course other exception types I do not handle explicitly, but those currently are not causing the trap to be executed.

Help is appreciated!!

Comment: You need to enable the trap *before* you call the python program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__cleanup` function is not executed when the Python script errs because the script exits before getting to the `trap __cleanup EXIT` statement which registers the handler. Place the `trap` statement and the `__cleanup` function at the top of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

__cleanup()
{
   echo "Build Lock Removed"
   [[ -f ".build.lock" ]] && rm ".build.lock"
}
trap __cleanup EXIT

if [[ -f ".build.lock" ]]; then
   echo "A build is already in progress by another user. Unable to continue, exiting."
   echo "   If this is a mistake, delete the '.build.lock' file to forcefully unlock"
   exit 1
else
   touch .build.lock
   echo "Build Lock Created"

   pushd ~/build-server-scripts > /dev/null

   # Execute main build script
   python3 my-build.py "$@"

   popd > /dev/null
fi
```